# Heroku, my app crashed.... H10 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I don't know how to solve this... I've pushed a rails app on heroku...

I ran `heroku logs`

and get this error **H10**

```
2016-08-17T20:03:59.649807+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=www.mywebsite.com request_id=1f963b41-1af7-4db7-ac73-f396080f8427 fwd="92.171.113.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-08-17T20:04:00.117304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.mywebsite.com request_id=040e8bb4-3bc8-44d8-8618-8b76c06ba483 fwd="92.171.113.21" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 0):

I found with the command `heroku run rails console`
I add a typo.... 
`password: ENV.["ADMIN_PASSWORD"]`
just gad to remove the dot